# how to prevent loading previous data when refresh the window using mouse. (right click on the tab and select reload tab option)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, youtube

I want to prevent load youtube video when window is refresh. by using keyboard F5 and browser refresh button it not loading. But when I right click on my window and select reload window option it loads previous youtube video.
Here is my code:

```js
var temp1;
    var temp2;
    var temp3 = 0;
    function showPlayer(id, iframe, src) {
        if (temp3 != 0) {
            $("#" + temp1 + "").addClass("hide");
            document.getElementById(temp2).src = "";
        }

        $("#" + id + "").removeClass("hide");
        document.getElementById(iframe).src = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/" + src + "?autoplay=1;controls=0&amp;showinfo=0";
        temp1 = id;
        temp2 = iframe;
        temp3++;
    }
```

```css
.a1{
        position: relative;
        height: 300px; 
        width: 400px; 
        overflow: hidden;
        background-color: #ddd;
    }
    .yt-player{
        border: solid 1px #000;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="a1" style="">
    <div id="b1" >
        <iframe id="yt-1" class="yt-player" width="300" height="175"   frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        <br/>
        <button onclick="showPlayer('b1', 'yt-1', 'fIHH5-HVS9o')">play video</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: doing reload clears the browser cache

Comment: yes by using F5 and browser refresh button page clears its data. but when I reload page using mouse right click it loads previous data. I want to prevent that also.

Comment: you want to prevent any refresh of the page, why?

Comment: because I don't want to play any video when page refresh. I want only play video by clicking play video button.

Comment: No I can't do that. because I want to play video automatically  when I click play video button.(just one click)

Comment: this means youtube developers  named this option wrong, it should name it toggle play not autoplay

Comment: my dear friend I feel you didn't get my question properly. So please go though my code and give suitable answer.

Comment: its hard to tell from your question what you want to do, sory